# error PLS-00103 while running a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, procedure

I am a newbie in plsql and trying to implement a code that uses procedure to perform some task.I am using oracle 10g.I have already made a package named stu_pack and am trying to make package body but in vain.Please help.
I want to make a procedure that gives student details for given course name.
the code is as below.

the error message is:

> ERROR at line 14: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when
>   expecting one of the following: ;      delete exists prior
>
> The symbol ";" was substituted for "PROCEDURE" to continue.
>
> create or replace package body stu_pack as
>      procedure proc1(cname IN number) as
>      l_cname number(2);

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY stu_pack AS

    PROCEDURE proc1 (
        cname IN NUMBER
    ) AS

        l_cname   NUMBER(2);
        cur1      student%rowtype;
        CURSOR c1 IS SELECT
            s.*
                     FROM
            student s,
            course c,
            learn l
                     WHERE
            c.cname = l_cname
            AND   c.cid = l.cid
            AND   s.sid = l.sid;

    BEGIN
        OPEN c1;
        LOOP
            FETCH c1 INTO cur1;
            EXIT WHEN c%notfound;
            dbms_output.put_line('student roll number:'
            || cur1.sid
            || ' student 
          name:'
            || cur1.sname
            || ' phone number:'
            || cur1.phone);

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE c1;
    END procedure proc1;

END stu_pack;
/
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: error message is :ERROR at line 14: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:

   ;  
   delete exists prior 
The symbol ";" was substituted for "PROCEDURE" to continue.
1. create or replace package body stu_pack as
2. procedure proc1(cname IN number) as
3. l_cname number(2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the line `end procedure proc1`;

It should be simply

```
end;
```

oR

```
end proc1;
```